# How can I keep show "password" instead of stars in password textmoded textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to show stars instead of password when I select password from database.

```
 txtPassword.text = usr.M_Password;
```

But after page load, password text box being empty however its textmode is password. And also when I write something in it, the stars shown. Do you have any idea about this?

KR,

Çağın

Comment: You never want to do this.  Your password will appear in the markup you send to the client.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add a Value Attribute to the Textbox using a randomly generated String with the exact amount of letters as the original Password instead, since this will appear in the markup, but it's the only way to actually set the shown text of a Password-TextBox. Your user will be under the illusion of his password being entered whilst you take the actual Password-Value from somewhere else (DB, Backend, etc.).

The password will be displayed in stars and it works across PostBacks, you can't simply set the Text-Property without working with JS.

Comment: won't that show the password in the markup? this is a very bad idea.

Comment: Oh, yes, it does, nevermind it then, alternately you could just set the value-Attribute of `txtPassword` with a string of the same count of letters as the original password, save the original password somewhere else and when it comes to authentication, pull the password from that "secret save spot". This way the user will be under the illusion of his password being saved whilst actually not giving it away in the markup.

Comment: "secret save spot"?  yeah it's called the Users memory or the browser's settings.  You can't dynamically set a textbox that is setup with textmode "password"

Comment: I don't see why you would deny a user the privilege of having its password stored somewhere after they are authenticated already. Also it's just about the illusion of the password being displayed there (in stars) from what I understood from OPs question. And the approach of just setting the value-Attribute with a random string of the same length isn't a security issue at all.

Comment: It appears what he wants to do is show a textbox which says "password"  when the focus is on the textbox and enter your password it shows as stars.  And a password should never be stored anywhere.  Only the slated hash should be, and never shown or stored in the markup delivered to the client machine.

Comment: I believe what he's looking for is how American Express does their login.  Go check it out.  You do that through hiding/showing different textboxes, or using ASP.NET AJAX watermark. (which does what I just mentioned)

Comment: His question (to me) very clearly states that he is trying to assign a value to the Password-Textbox, so he indeed wants the password to be entered into that (Password-)TextBox automatically. He just couldn't succeed because you cannot set the Text-Property of a Password-TextBox. Of course I don't believe myself to be an Oracle to be 100% sure what he wanted, but from my point of view this could solve it.

Comment: He's probably asking because he wants to pre-populate the password textbox, which you shouldn't do because the password will appear in the markup.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, I updated my answer, now it's for the OP to decide.

Answer (score 0):

An `<asp:TextBox />` with a `textmode` of password is Read Only.

You can't dynamically set the value.

You'll need to have two textboxes.  One where the textmode is normal, and one where the textmode is password.

When the focus is set on the normal textbox, you'll need to hide it, and then show the textbox with textmode as password.  You can't set the value of the password textbox from the database, again, as it is read only.

Answer (score -2):

You must be resetting the value of the `txtPassword.Text` property somewhere, or the value you're pulling back from the database is actually empty. Post more code for a better response.